# Can't add custom collectionViewCell as subview

Tags: ios

I have created a customCollectionViewCell and I need to display a dataSource element separately from the collectionView. For this I am explicitly creating the custom cell and adding it as a subview to one of my views. The cells are getting displayed fine inside the collectionView. Can anyone help? :(

Comment: Sounds like poor design to me. What's the error you are getting? If you really must use a collection view as a subview of a UIView, use a content view on the collection view cell and add that to your UIView. I would find a more appropriate approach though.

Comment: I have tried that already. Still doesn't work. I know that it's not a conventional method. But I really want to know the reason.

Comment: Adding a UIView (which is what a cell content view will be) to another UIView does work. What's your error exactly? Have you loaded the cell properly? You can't use 'init' for this if it's coming off a storyboard or xib file.